# Twitter Boostrap apply class only for desktop versions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap dropdown menu. On desktop versions I want it to be clickable. By clickable I mean not only it to work as dropdown but also as a normal button. If users hovers on it it will expand others menu but if user clicks on it it will redirect to another page. That is why it has `.disabled` class applied. But I don't want this class to be applied when user is using mobile device so if a user clicks on it it will only expand. Thats the reason why I need `.disabled` class to be applied only for desktops. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="somePath" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown">DropDown</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you should use media css as below, to accomplish this. This would be easier to do.

```
@media (min-width: 990px){
    .disabled {
    //do your styles here
    }
}
```

and for the other  screen sizes just give the default styles that has to be applied. Try it.

**UPDATE**

You can add the class `disabled` dynamically using JavaScript, if the screen size is large, as below

```
function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 990) {
     $('.newClass').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else {$('.newClass').removeClass('disabled');}
}
```

and call the function in `$(document).ready()` as

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(window).resize(resize);
    resize();
});
```

Also, while trying this, dont forget to add a class to the `<a>` such that it becomes

```
<a href="somePath" class="dropdown-toggle newClass" data-toggle="dropdown">DropDown</a>
```

Comment: .disabled class is default bootstrap class. I believe this would mean that I have to modify it and that wouldn't be a clean solution or am I wrong?

Comment: clean solution...i think, that is dependent..:D..if you need it, you should override it..

Comment: There is another problem. That class is used in bootstrap.js for it's effect I need. and just overriding that class using @media simply won't work